# How to put the data from the textbox into the empty rows of grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show 16 empty rows in a gridview of asp.net. I have a button and textbox outside the grid, on a button click, I have to insert the data from the textbox into the grid but the problem is that the data inserted after the 16 rows. How the data will be inserted in empty rows first.?
I bound the datasource with null but the grid is not visible so i create the rows on pageload event..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("DateTime");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Detail");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Status");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Cancel");
                   for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
                     {
                       dtSource.Rows.Add("", " ", " ", " ");
                     }
                    ViewState["dtSource"] = dtSource;
                    gridItem.DataSource = dtSource;
                    gridItem.DataBind();

            }
        }
```

and here is the code for the button

```
protected void btnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtSource = ViewState["dtSource"] as DataTable;          
            DataRow dr = dtSource.NewRow();
            dtSource.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, itemDetail, "", "");
            gridItem.DataSource = dtSource;
            gridItem.DataBind();
            ViewState["dtSource"] = dtSource;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are creating a new row and adding it like below

```
DataRow dr = dtSource.NewRow();
```

There is no point in adding those 16 rows. You should rather do something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               DataTable dtSource = new DataTable();
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("DateTime");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Detail");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Status");
                    dtSource.Columns.Add("Cancel");
                    ViewState["dtSource"] = dtSource;
                    gridItem.DataSource = dtSource;
                    gridItem.DataBind();

            }
        }


protected void btnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtSource = ViewState["dtSource"] as DataTable;          
            DataRow dr = dtSource.NewRow();
            dtSource.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, itemDetail, "", "");
            gridItem.DataSource = dtSource;
            gridItem.DataBind();
            ViewState["dtSource"] = dtSource;
        }
```

Comment: But to show empty row is the requirement. Will you please give me some other idea to show the empty row.
If i use ur code of pageload then my grid is hide.